# Configure Jackson Mapper from Xml

Tags: json, jackson, dto

I need to generate Json from the domain object. I can't add annotation in the domain classes.

Using Mixin is not a option because I have to ignore a lot of properties.

My approach was create a DTO object with the properties that I need. And populate the dto using dozer and then generate Json from the dto with jackson. It looks too much.

I would like to know if is posible to configure Jackson from xml, in order to generate json with the properties mapped in the xml, so it would not be necessary to use dto and dozer.

Answer (score 0):

No. Jackson does not support external configuration files.

But you don't explain how or why you would use Dozer, or DTO. Why not just add properties you care about in a `Map`, and serialize that as JSON? Then you can use whatever mechanism you want to build/trim that `Map`.

Jackson can also convert values, so to create full Map with everything from another object, you can do:

```
Map<String,Object> map = objectMapper.convertValue(someBean, Map.class);
```

and maybe then only retain properties you want.